# bash while-loop stops unexpectedly

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to code a bash script using the while-loop, but it stops after 10-12 iterations... what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

expressvpn disconnect

while : 
do
    expressvpn connect
    sleep 6
    xdg-open http://link
    sleep 15
    xdotool key Control_L+w
    expressvpn disconnect
    sleep 3
done
```

This simple bash script is driving me crazy and it gives me no clue about the problem... it just stops after connecting or while opening a new tab with xdg-open. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try to add this two lines set -x and trap read DEBUG under #!/bin/bash to debug your code or/and try with while ((1>0)).

Comment: Your script has correct syntax. Your issue is most likely not related to programming, but rather to your configuration.

Comment: @Aserre what do you mean by configuration?

Comment: Your linux environment and tool configuration (what other processes are running, is expressvpn connecting/disconnecting properly or is it throwing an uncatched error, etc ...). Have you tried adding `set -x; trap read DEBUG` at the begining of your script as suggested in the comments ? It should show you which process the shell is executing and the status of your script.

Comment: Yes, here's what I get as output 
`pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ ./typert
+ trap read DEBUG
++ read
`

Comment: Oh, I got it lol, I just had to press enter.